# Configure Lens with GKE cluster - gke_gcloud_auth_plugin issue

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gcloud, k8slens

I was able to access my kubernetes cluster using `kubectl` after authenticating to Google Cloud `gcloud auth login --cred-file=sa.json`

I installed **gke-gcloud-auth-plugin** too (`gcloud components install gke-gcloud-auth-plugin`)

However I wasn't able to access the cluster with Lens ! I got the following error

[image]

I was able to connect to the cluster, but I can't see any resource !

Answer (score 0):

if you noticed the error message carefully `failed to load events *** can't list resource 'evnt. in the API groups at the cluster scope requires "container.events.list"`  seems there is an [RBAC configured at cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#role-and-clusterrole) level, and you lack a`container.events.list` permission.  Therefore, my advice would be to check with the cluster admin and get the required permission.

[Authorize actions in clusters using role-based access control](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/role-based-access-control)

Comment: But I can access the pods with **kubectl** with the same suer

Comment: maybe Lens doesn't have the necessary permissions configured !

Comment: Can you explain a bit about this Lens? I am new to it